# Core Data Fetching Properties with Group By Count

Tags: objective-c, core-data

This is the SQL version of the query I would like to write for Core Data:

```
SELECT Group.Name, COUNT(Item.Name)
FROM Item INNER JOIN Group ON Item.GroupID = Group.ID
GROUP BY Group.Name
```

So far what I have is:

```
NSFetchRequest* fetchGroupSummary = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Item"];

NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:[[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] managedObjectContext]];

NSAttributeDescription* groupName = [entity.relationshipsByName objectForKey:@"group"];
NSExpression *countExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction: @"count:" arguments: [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath: @"name"]]];
NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];

[expressionDescription setName: @"count"];
[expressionDescription setExpression: countExpression];
[expressionDescription setExpressionResultType: NSInteger32AttributeType];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"group.sort" ascending:YES];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"group.stage == %@", stage];

[fetchGroupSummary setEntity:entity];
[fetchGroupSummary setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
[fetchGroupSummary setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:groupName, expressionDescription, nil]];
[fetchGroupSummary setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObject:groupName]];
[fetchGroupSummary setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[fetchGroupSummary setPredicate:predicate];

NSError* error = nil;
groups = [[[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchGroupSummary error:&error];

expressionDescription = nil;
```

This almost gives me everything, however instead of groupName being the group relationship I would like to specify group.name - is this possible?

Mark

Comment: Have you tried `[fetchGroupSummary setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"group.name"]]` ?

Comment: Martin, that worked perfectly! If you add it as an answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`setPropertiesToGroupBy` of `NSFetchRequest` accepts an array of `NSPropertyDescription` or `NSExpressionDescription` objects, or *keypath strings*. In your case, you can use a keypath string:

```
[fetchGroupSummary setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"group.name"]];
```

Comment: I'm trying to group a result set by a property that is in it. But it crashes with the error **Invalid fetch request: GROUP BY requires NSDictionaryResultType**. [This](http://pastebin.com/JHv87nFd) is my code. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: @Isuru: `fetchRequest.resultType = .DictionaryResultType`. The mapping between (Objective-)C enumerations and Swift enums is described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html.

Comment: I just did that but I get a new error now **SELECT clauses in queries with GROUP BY components can only contain properties named in the GROUP BY or aggregate functions**

Comment: @Isuru: You probably have also to set `propertiesToFetch`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I specified each and every property name but still the same error. :/ Shall I post a separate question with more details?

Comment: @Isuru have you solved the problem with GROUP BY property names?