# Sum of distinct values in core data

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a core data model in my app that consists of some non distinct dates. Each date has a quantity value. Now i wanna get sum of each date in one query. Note that the dates are not distinct meaning there are more than one 2015/01/05 and so on.

Im new to core data and really struggling with this stuff. Any idea how to achieve this.

Comment: Can you provide more detail of your model - is the date in question modelled as NSDate?  If so, do you strip out the time info?  How?

Comment: No the data is in string format and composed of year month value like: 201509, 201501

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637440/is-it-possible-to-use-group-concat-with-coredata/ is similar, and has a longer code sample. But it doesn't have @pbasdf's nice `@sum` expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is using `NSExpression` to calculate the sum, and `propertiesToGroupBy` to limit the scope of the sum to each distinct date.  Assuming your date attribute is called `yearMonth` and the value you want to sum is called `quantity`:

```
NSExpression *sumExp = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"sum:(quantity)"];
NSExpressionDescription *sumED = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
sumED.name = @"sumOfQuantity";
sumED.expression = sumExp;
sumED.expressionResultType = NSDoubleAttributeType;
NSError *error;
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"YourEntityName"];
request.propertiesToFetch = @[@"yearMonth", sumED];
request.propertiesToGroupBy = @[@"yearMonth"];
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSLog(@"Sums of quantity by year/month are: %@", results);
```

The results should be an array of dictionaries, each with two keys: "yearMonth" as a key for date, and "sumOfQuantity" as a key for the corresponding sum.